# Can a DQN output a float result?

Tags: dqn

I'm a newbie of Deep Q Learning. After read some papers and tutorials on the web, I tried to train a DQN to control a game using TensorFlow.

The input is the screenshoot of the game. The output is an float array [x, y](where 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1), which contorls the tap location of the screen.

But I found that almost all the DQN I saw before only has a discrete, and they can use the tf.one_hot function to generate all the state table easily.
And I don't know how to deal with my float output and how to perform my backpropagation with this float output.

How can train the to DQN output such a float result and perform a backpropagation?

Comment: I don't think it's too broad at all. Basically, it's asked if a DQN could output a continuous value. It has also a simple answer: no. However, nothing stops you to use other Q-learning algorithms such as _continuous DQN with normalized advantage function_. It was developed for this specific reason.